# Which errors could happen with PDO $stmt->fetch()?

Tags: php, pdo, try-catch

I found this example code at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php#example-926):

```
function readDataForwards($dbh) {
  $sql = 'SELECT hand, won, bet FROM mynumbers ORDER BY BET';
  try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
      $data = $row[0] . "\t" . $row[1] . "\t" . $row[2] . "\n";
      print $data;
    }
    $stmt = null;
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

My experience is that an exception happens only if `$dbh->prepare` fails (sql server has gone away, wrong sql statement, etc.) and as it is possible that my code contains inside of the `while()` an additional sql query (with nested `try/catch` blocks) I like to know if and what errors I would miss by moving the `catch (...) {...}` part as follows resulting a more clearly arranged code:

```
function readDataForwards($dbh) {
  $sql = 'SELECT hand, won, bet FROM mynumbers ORDER BY BET';
  try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
    $stmt->execute();
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    $stmt = new AnObj();
    $stmt->fetch = function() { return false; };
    print $e->getMessage();
  }
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
    $data = $row[0] . "\t" . $row[1] . "\t" . $row[2] . "\n";
    print $data;
  }
  $stmt = null;
}
```

So which exceptions can be caused through `$stmt->fetch()` I do not like to miss?

Update: [AnObj](https://gist.github.com/Mihailoff/3700483) added.

Comment: `$stmt` would remain undefined if an exception occurs. So you should guard the `while` condition, either with an `if` or perhaps just `while ($stmt and $row = ..)`

Comment: I think the best is just drop the AnObj you've added and just add test for stmt object before the while. It is simple, functional and easy to understand.

Comment: Ignore that. Thats not my question.